# How to automatically add module dependencies to feature with Ctools exportables?

Tags: 7, features, chaos-tool-suite

I created an API module with a hook_schema(), where one table has an ['export' key](https://www.drupal.org/node/928026) to make the entries exportable with [ctools](//drupal.org/project/ctools) (as [features](//drupal.org/project/features)).

Now specific entries of this module may depend on specific modules. I would like these module dependencies to be added automatically to a feature exported this way.

Any idea how this is done?

Comment: I don't know exactly how, but I think it's done using [`hook_features_pipe_COMPONENT_alter`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21features%21features.api.php/function/hook_features_pipe_COMPONENT_alter/7)

Comment: This looks good. But not all data is provided in this hook. Only the machine names of the exported entries, but not their data.

Comment: Sorry I don't really know how to implement this myself. You can check other modules and see how they do it too :) If you find a solution, it'll be interesting to see. Please post it.

Comment: One can simply load this information from elsewhere.